# React Native: How to have a new screen to replace the current screen in a tab navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Lets say the app has two tabs, the first one has 10 buttons, each button commands the second tab to show a different screen. And I want the new screen to replace the old one when the button is pressed; I don't want the new screen to stack on top of the old one.
So far I've achieved this by rendering all ten screens with a boolean state for each that determines whether it returns anything or not, but rendering them all at the same time has slowed the app down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a route in the navigation state you can use :

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.replace('Profile', {
    user: 'jane',
  })
);
```

source : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but does it work on tab navigator as well?